# Overriding ExceptionHandler in Ionic2 app

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

I'm working on an Ionic v2 App and was trying to implement this [ExceptionHandler](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ExceptionHandler-class.html) from angular2.

Since Ionic2 doesn't require the developer to explicitly call `bootstrap` it seems like there is no way to implement this for the time being.  Has anyone had any success for implementing a custom ExceptionHandler in Ionic v2?

Here was my attempt, but it fails to load the app, without any exceptions on the page.

```
import {ExceptionHandler,provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/bootstrap';

import {AppExceptionHandler} from './services/exception-service';


...

bootstrap(MyApp,provide(ExceptionHandler, {useClass: AppExceptionHandler }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override this in the `MyApp` component

```
@Component({
    providers: [provide(ExceptionHandler, {useClass: AppExceptionHandler})]
})
export class MyApp{...}
```